# Express double request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating an application on express. I want to get a specific user's page, but I have a request for /:id executed 2 times. And the second time it is called from the file app.js . Although I don't have such a file in the project. I really ask you to help me!

index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')

const homeRouter = require('./routes/homeRouter')
const addRouter = require('./routes/addRouter')
const usersRouter = require('./routes/usersRouter')

const app = express()
const port = 3000
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs',
})

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', 'views')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use('/', homeRouter)
app.use('/add', addRouter)
app.use('/users', usersRouter)

async function start() {
    try {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Sever is running on ${port} port...`)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

userRouter.js:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const User = require('../models/user.js')
const router = Router()

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Запрос /')
    const users = await User.getAll()
    res.render('users', {
        title: 'Пользователи',
        isUsers: true,
        users: users,
    })
})

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Запрос /:id')
    const user = await User.getById(req.params.id)
    console.log(user)
    res.render('user', {
        title: user.name + ' ' + user.surname,
        user: user,
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

user.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid')

class User {
    constructor(name, surname, phoneNumber, email, avatar) {
        this.id = uuidv4()
        this.name = name
        this.surname = surname
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        this.email = email
        this.avatar = avatar
    }

    async save() {
        const allUsers = await User.getAll()
        allUsers.push({
            id: this.id,
            name: this.name,
            surname: this.surname,
            phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
            email: this.email,
            avatar: this.avatar,
        })

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.writeFile(
                path.join(__dirname, '..', 'data', 'users.json'),
                JSON.stringify(allUsers),
                (err) => {
                    if (err) reject(err)
                    else resolve()
                }
            )
        })
    }

    static async getAll() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile(
                path.join(__dirname, '..', 'data', 'users.json'),
                'utf-8',
                (err, data) => {
                    if (err) reject(err)
                    resolve(JSON.parse(data))
                }
            )
        })
    }

    static async getById(uid) {
        const allUsers = await User.getAll()
        const user = allUsers.find(u => u.id === uid)
        return user
    }
}

module.exports = User
```

Due to the fact that I call /:id 2 times, my program does not work correctly. How do I fix this?

Comment: I would register your `homeRouter` **after** the other two since it is less specific